# But not in [Browsername here] SEDE Query

Tags: support, data-explorer

So, regularly questions pop up with "It works in all Browsers But not in [browser]"

In Google search

- "but not in chrome" site:stackoverflow.com
  Yields 38.000 results
- "but not in firefox" site:stackoverflow.com
  Yields 31.800 results
- "but not in IE" site:stackoverflow.com
  Yields 27.300 results

So since I found this an interesting tidbit I tried to build some SEDE queries, but I can't build a proper SEDE query that won't time-out on the like query on title or text.

Does anyone have a suggestion how to build a SEDE query that would filter these data points so they become manageable for the engine to return results?

Answer (score 2):

There are several options. One is to limit your search scope to a single tag and use a TOP with a reasonable number.

Here is a [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/858639?tagname=javascript&body=but+not+in+firefox) where I applied that technique.

```sql
select top 100 
       p.id as [Post Link]
from posts p
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = p.id
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
where t.tagname = ##tagname:string?javascript##
and body like '%##body##%' collate sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_ai
```

Other options are to limit on the `creationdate` (use a BETWEEN statement).

Don't forget that SEDE has an option to include the execution plan (the query needs to run or alternatively use the `set showplan_all on` statement)

[image: execution plan]

You can apply SQL Server statement tuning techniques to improve the performance of the query.

There is a known issue with the Magic Link Columns (like [Post Link]) that cause an out of resources error even for small resultsets. I have answered a similar question about that topic: [Out-of-resources when trying to run a popular DataExplorer query](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284040/out-of-resources-when-trying-to-run-a-popular-dataexplorer-query/284086#284086) with both an analysis of the root cause and offer a work around.